# How I get saved item from AsyncStorage in different .js class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
saveValueFunction = () => {
    if(this.state.textInputData){
      AsyncStorage.setItem('KEYVALUE', this.state.textInputData);
      console.log("DATA SAVED" +this.state.textInputData)
      this.setState({ textInputData: '' })
      alert('Data Saved');
    }else{
      alert('Please fill data');
    }
};
```

**this code i used in first.js class and i want to get its value in Second.js class for this i'm using this code in Second.js class**

```
 constructor() {
       super();
       AsyncStorage.getItem('KEYVALUE').then(value =>
           this.setState({ getValue: value })
       );
 }
```

**But I getting this error TypeError: null is not an Object (evaluating 'this.state.getValue')**

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you must not use any async code within constructor but within `componentDidMount`.

**Secondly**, the error that you get is because you haven't initialised state in constructor and trying to run setState

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {};
}
componentDidMount() {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('KEYVALUE').then(value =>
           this.setState({ getValue: value })
   );
}
```

Comment: glad to have helped.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem